# The AR Session Failed. One or more reference images have an invalid size

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

Xcode: 10.1 beta
Swift: 4
AR kit: 2.0

When starting our AR Session we've been running into:

> **The AR Session failed.**
>
> Invalid reference image.
>
> One or more reference images have an invalid size: [file name].
>
> Make sure that all reference images are greater than 100 pixels and have a positive physical size in meters.

We've checked:

- our reference image is greater than 100 pixels
- our reference image has a positive physical size in meters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

[This post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/arkit-2-0-beta-support.534639/)

stated:

> the error message is a bit missleading. Try setting your Deployment Target (in Unity or later in Xcode) to 12.0. This fixes the issue for me.

Which has fixed our issue.

**Solution 2**

Additionally, leaving our Deployment Target as is (`10.0`) and ensuring that the reference image is a `.jpg` has also solved this for us.

Answer (score 2):

After trying and failing in all the above, in my case after a lot of trial and error i realised the problem happened because i had exactly the same image with the same file name as the reference image, in a normal asset catalog (ie a duplicate, in a yellow folder). Changing the name of the reference image to a different one fixed it.

Comment: My heart goes out to you, that's rough